# Unable to connect SQL DB using ADO.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am .NET developer using C# technology. I have used ADO.net for MS SQL DB connection. I have used below connection string in my config file.It's working perfectly in my local DB.

```
connectionString="Server=192.168.1.3;Initial Catalog=Company;User Id=admin;Password=abc@123;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

But I am unable to connect DB with one of my bank client. I am not sure how they have design DB but they just told me that they are using ServerName/DBName together while connecting from DB where as I am using two separate data for connection. It's bank client so they are not disclosing all other details.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue if you anytime configure DB in such a way.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rajeev

Comment: Sounds like they are simply stating they have an instance that runs on the SQL server so it would be something like this in your connecting string Server:ServerName\InstanceName then your catalog would be the DB name.

Comment: Finally I identified this issue. This was happening due to not sufficient privilege to provided user. Thanks for your support